# How to change a background color of a static window in win32API?

Tags: winapi

im trying to change the color of an edit,and a static window in win32API please help. I don’t have an idea on how can I accomplish that.

Comment: Handle the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to change the edit's color. Regarding the window, what do you mean by static window?

Comment: I mean mainWin = createwindowW(L”static”,”mywin”,ws_chiled,20,20,50,100,NULL,NULL,NULL);   I tried to use something like colorstatic but it change the background color of every static window in the program

Comment: @PeaceBytheway The `WM_CTLCOLOR...` messages tell you which `HWND` is currently being drawn in each message. Use that information to selectively choose which controls you want to apply your colors to, and which controls you want to skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window procedure for the *parent window* of the `EDIT` and `STATIC` controls can handle the [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) and [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic) messages, respectively.

> An edit control that is not read-only or disabled sends the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use the specified device context handle to set the text and background colors of the edit control.

> A static control, or an edit control that is read-only or disabled, sends the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use the specified device context handle to set the text foreground and background colors of the static control.

Comment: owk thank you , can i please have an example?